# Compare location of two imageview

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

Is there any condition for checking the location of two image views such that when one image view is dragged and dropped , the image view should fit the size of the dropped image view.

For example,

ImageView1 - consists of an image eg: car

ImageView2 and ImageView3 - empty image views

Imageview1 dragged and dropped on imageView2 ( imageview1 fits imageviews2)

But according to my logic, both the image views are getting fit

```
imageView1.buildDrawingCache(); Bitmap src = ImageView1.getDrawingCache(); 
BitmapDrawable destDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(src,image1.getWidth(), image1.getHeight(), false));

BitmapDrawable destDrawable1 = new BitmapDrawable(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(src,image2.getWidth(), image2.getHeight(), false));

image1.setImageDrawable(destDrawable);
image2.setImageDrawable(destDrawable1);
```

Comment: I don't think I got your question. "both the image views are getting fit"? Isn't that what you want?

Comment: So as long as the image that is dropped intersects with the image in place, you want the dropped image to fit the size of the image in place?

Comment: yes according to the above logic, the image gets fit into both the imageviews regardless of the dropped position, I need in such a way that 1-1 imageview ie. when one image view is dropped, it should fit only image1 and not image2

Comment: @remedy. yes you are correct. only one image view needs to get fit

Comment: IS there any if conditions for checking the locations of imageviews?

Comment: So have you done any detection yet to see whether or not your image that you are dropping is overlaying the image in place?

Comment: No, I am just confused with the logic how it turns up.